# How to bind a value from one ng-model to an other by matching a specific string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I got a requirement to bind a value to a particular model when the value in the other model contains a string starting with "https".

For example, I have two text fields both fields having different model

```
<input type="text" ng-model="modelText1"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="modelText2">
```

Suppose I type a value on the first text field "https", the first input model modelText1 have to bind to the second input model modelText2 and later on i have to maintain it as like two-way binding. i.e. the second field will automatically get the value dynamically when it contains "https" at starting of a string.

Comment: 4 good answers :) The force is with you.

Comment: thank u guys for reply, i dont need strong type, the values of the fields must have have two-way binding after the condition equals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like in this <kbd>**[`Demo fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ga8vhk/9/)**</kbd>.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="modelText1"> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="modelText2"> 
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modelText1 = '';
    $scope.modelText2 = '';

    var regEx = new RegExp(/^https/);

    $scope.$watch('modelText1', function (newValue) {
       if (newValue.toLowerCase().match(regEx)) {
          $scope.modelText2 = newValue;
       } else {
          $scope.modelText2 = '';
       }
    });
});
```

---

An other approach is (that avoid using of `$watch`) is to use AngularJS `ng-change` like in this

<kbd>**[`example fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ke6hgdsn/3/)**</kbd>.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="modelText1" ng-change="change()"> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="modelText2"> 
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modelText1 = '';
    $scope.modelText2 = '';
    var regEx = new RegExp(/^https/);

    $scope.change = function () {
       if ($scope.modelText1.toLowerCase().match(regEx)) {
          $scope.modelText2 = $scope.modelText1;
       } else {
          $scope.modelText2 = '';
       }
    };
});
```

Comment: U did strong type checking.It will fail if you type HTTPS.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN right as in the spec `equal to "https".`->  HTTPS !== https m8 =)

Comment: i dont need strong type, the values of the fields must have have two-way binding after the condition equals. @lin

Comment: @SukumarDhoni allright! I just updated the answer and demos!

Comment: i haven't seen any difference, working same as before @lin

Comment: @SukumarDhoni `.toLowerCase()`. It now works with `https`, `Https`, `HTTPS`, `hTtPs`, and so on.

Comment: what i actually mean is that after the 'https' condition satisfies if i type 'www' in the first field  it should also bind in the second field like as two way binding in feilds

Comment: @SukumarDhoni please describe carefully what you want to achieve. Your requirments are not fully described.

Comment: @SukumarDhoni you sound like a client asking for a job to be done- not a developer who is stuck in some sort of problem. Be a MAN.

Comment: @SukumarDhoni please be carefull next time to describe your requirements. The solution you looking for wasn't the one you described in the question. Means: `equal to "https"` does not mean `contain a string  "https" at start of the string`.

Comment: my sincere apologies.i got this thought after posted. i have updated my question

Comment: @SukumarDhoni Is my answer obsolete now? -.-

Comment: Almost Yes!, i had changed the condition using regular exp

Comment: please update ur fiddle mr lin. i have edited your answer. now ur answer reflects my question.

Comment: @SukumarDhoni make it work the right way. The answer is now up2date. This is kind of reverse engineering. :)

Comment: yeah @lin. ur absolutely right. happy ending. healthy discussion.

Answer (score 2):

use `ng-change`  to check the text is equal to 'https'

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.changeItem = function(item){
   
  $scope.modelText2 = "";
    if(item.toLowerCase() === "https"){
      $scope.modelText2 = item
    }
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="modelText1" ng-change="changeItem(modelText1)"> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="modelText2"> 
</div>
```

**EDiTED**

to make sure it does't fail under 'HTTPS' use `toLoweCase` function to make all lower case

Comment: U did strong type checking.It will fail if you type HTTPS

Comment: As I allready said the specs are `equal to "https"`. HTTPS is not equal to https, so its right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="modelText1" ng-change="onChange()"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="modelText2">
```

and your controller:

```
$scope.onChange = function() {
   if ($scope.modelText1 === 'https') {
     $scope.modelText2 = $scope.modelText1;
   else
     $scope.modelText2 = '';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="modelText1" ng-change="updateModal(modelText1)">
```

JS :

```
var modelText1 = $scope.modelText1.toLowerCase();

    $scope.updateModal = function(){
        $scope.modelText2 = '';
        if(modelText1.indexOf('https')!=-1){
              $scope.modelText2 = modelText1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you could also possibly do this as a directive if you want to have a more reusable solution over multiple views http://jsfiddle.net/j5ga8vhk/7/
It also keeps the controller more clean, i always try to use the controller only for controlling complex business logic and business data

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="modelText1" > 
  <input type="text" ng-model="modelText2" model-listener="modelText1" model-listener-value="https" > 
</div>
```

**Angular JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.modelText1 = '';
        $scope.modelText2 = '';

        });


myApp.directive('modelListener', [function()    {

    return {

        restrict: 'A',

        controller: ['$scope',  function($scope) {

        }],
        link: function($scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {

            $scope.$watch(iAttrs.modelListener, function() {

                if($scope[iAttrs.modelListener] === iAttrs.modelListenerValue ) {
                   $scope[iAttrs.ngModel] = $scope[iAttrs.modelListener];
                } else {
                    $scope[iAttrs.ngModel] = "";
                }
            }, true);

        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: No need for a directive - KISS https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS-principe